# How to get index of element in Set object

Tags: python

I have something like this:

```
numberList = {}
        for item in results:
            data = json.loads(item[0])
            if data[key] in itemList:
                numberList[itemList.index(data[key])] += 1
        print numberList
```

where itemList is 'set' object. How can I access index of single element in it ?

Comment: AFAIK, sets are not ordered.

Comment: `itemList` *must* be a `list`, not a `set`; `set` objects do *not* have a `.index()` method; `set` objects are in fact unordered.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Count the number of times a specific value of `data[key]` is present?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Count the number of times a specific value of data[key] is present? 

yeah, exactly

Comment: Then you don't *need* an index, do you? Just use `numberList[data[key]] += 1` and you are done.

Comment: I have to check unique names of cars from database and I have them inside of this itemList. Now i want to check how many Opel, Hondas are in this. Elements of this set are strings.

Comment: Perhaps you should rename `itemList` to `itemSet`, or even more descriptively, `items_seen`...

Comment: I did it without set object, I used list

Answer (score 79, accepted):

A set is just an unordered collection of unique elements. So, an element is either in a set or it isn't. This means that no element in a set has an index.

Consider the set `{1, 2, 3}`. The set contains 3 elements: 1, 2, and 3. There's no concept of indices or order here; the set just contains those 3 values.

So, if `data[key] in itemList` returns `True`, then `data[key]` is an element of the `itemList` set, but there's no index that you can obtain.

Comment: Ok, thank You for this information, it will be really helpful for me in the future.

Comment: Sets of ints are always in ascending order irrespective of the manner we add them. Isnt this an `order`

Comment: What about the Axiom of Choice! Haven't the creators of Python heard of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory?

Comment: @sziraqui That's not true. Sometimes they are, but generally not.

Answer (score 7):

Convert the set into list and you can use index() function in that list

```
Example:
x = {1,2,3};
x = list(x);
print(x.index(1))
```