# Can we use to Python script to create a comment?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to create a table using SQLite3 in Python. I have a set such as

```
Set = set(['CY110', 'PH100', 'CY100', 'CS100', 'BE110'])
```

Boiler-plate for normal create table condition:

```
sql_create_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS marks (id integer PRIMARY KEY,name text NOT NULL, );"""
```

The problem that I encounter is that I need to include each element like this:

```
sql_create_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS marks (id integer PRIMARY KEY,name text NOT NULL,CY100 text,PH100 text,CS100 text,BE100 text);"""
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator expression and join the output with `','` to produce the query string you want:

```
sql_create_table = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS marks (id integer PRIMARY KEY,name text NOT NULL,' + ','.join('%s text' % c for c in Set)
```

With your sample input, `sql_create_table` would become:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS marks (id integer PRIMARY KEY,name text NOT NULL,BE110 text,CS100 text,CY100 text,PH100 text,CY110 text
```

Answer (score 0):

It you just want to format a string from that set you can use the following. Also consider something other than `Set` for the name:

```
mySet = set(['CY110', 'PH100', 'CY100', 'CS100', 'BE110'])
mySet = list(mySet)  

sql_create_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS marks (id integer PRIMARY KEY,name text NOT NULL,{0} text,{1} text,{2} text,{3} text);""".format(mySet[0],mySet[1],mySet[2],mySet[3])

print(sql_create_table)
```

You cannot index the set directly to format the string without converting to a list because sets are not ordered as explained in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329308/how-to-get-index-of-element-in-set-object)